# ActionBar share item produces "Android System" thingy

Tags: android, android-intent, menu, share

I want a share icon in the action bar, upon pressing, a chooser shows up. I have most of this in place, but this unwelcome middle-man steps in...

**The menu:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
          android:title="@string/share"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    />    
</menu>
```

**The SherlockFragment's onCreateOptionsMenu:**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {     
    // Inflate menu resource file.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);

    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    this.shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    final String title = r.getString(R.string.feedback_share);
    final String subject = r.getString(R.string.share_subject);
    final String message = r.getString(R.string.share_message_plain);

    Intent intent = app.newShareIntent(title, subject, message);
    this.shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
}
```

**The intent factory:**

```
public Intent newShareIntent(String title, String subject, String message) {            
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
    chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    return chooser;
}
```

**The unwelcome middle-man:**

[image]

And when I click on this guy, he does as directed and presents the chooser. But I'm really not interested in engaging his services.

What I'm after:

[image]

Or this with all three (or however many on users devices) in the drop down... or be able to set the default that appears inline with the share icon:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I'm really not interested in engaging his services.

But you asked for "his services", as you're the one who called `createChooser()` and decided to use that as your share `Intent`.

Get rid of that, returning your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` directly, and "Android System" should go away.

Comment: Ok that worked... any way to get them into the dropdown? See edit

Comment: @psoft: I am afraid that I don't understand your question.

Comment: In my last screenshot you can see the bluetooth icon alongside the share icon in the actionbar. I want the bluetooth icon in the vertical list with the others (messaging, email, etc).

Comment: @psoft: Try `setShareHistoryFileName(null)`. I think the icon to the right is based off of the history.

Comment: how about creating chooser instead of pulling a list?